# Want to toggle a divs with two different selectors - one for show one for hide

Tags: jquery

I have a div that expands down once it is clicked. Once the div is open however, I want the div to be sent back to its original height by clicking an arrow that is located inside the div. I'm running into trouble because now whenever the arrow is clicked, the div quickly animates back to its original state because i am also clicking within the surrounding div. Is there a way to make sure that only the arrow is being clicked and that its action overrides the action of the surrounding div? Here's my code for the animation:

```
$("#box1").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
    val = 500;
    $this.stop().animate({
        width: '100%',
        height: val
    }, "slow");
    $("#cat_title1").stop().hide("slow");
    $("#cat_content1").stop().show("slow");
    $("#up1").stop().show("slow");
});

$("#up1").click(function () {
    $("#cat_content1").stop().hide("slow");
    $("#up1").stop().hide("slow");
    val = 100;
    $("#box1").stop().animate({
        width: '100%',
        height: val
    }, "slow");
    $("#cat_title1").stop().show("slow");
});
```

"#box1" is the div, when its clicked it expands.

then there is an arrow that appears inside the div called "#up1". when this is clicked, the div should then animate back to its unexpanded form.

Thanks for your help with this one.

Best,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to this:

```
$("#up1").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#cat_content1").stop().hide("slow");
    $("#up1").stop().hide("slow");
    val = 100;
    $("#box1").stop().animate({
        width: '100%',
        height: val
    }, "slow");
    $("#cat_title1").stop().show("slow");
});
```

`e.stopPropagation()` will prevent the event from bubbling up to the parent div and the parent div's click handler won't be triggered.